# how redirect my treeview menu with material 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use the Treeview of material UI 4,
however I do not know how to add a parameter to integrate my redirects to other pages during the click.
before I used a system of

https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use onNodeToggle prop on TreeView:

> Callback fired when a TreeItem is expanded/collapsed.

here is a simple example:

```
const onNodeToggle = (nodeId, isExpanded) => {
  switch(nodeId) {
    case "1": 
      //redirect to other page code..
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

don't forget to provide this function as prop to treeView:

```
<TreeView
  // other treeview props.. \\
  onNodeToggle={onNodeToggle}
>
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hy23u?fontsize=14) example